# Need to set Tapku Calendar to only have certain dates selectable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, tapku

I'm using the `Tapku Library` (http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers) to implement a Monthly Calendar View for my application, but the thing is that I only want certain days in the Calendar View to be selectable, based on an array of `NSDates` that I have.

I suppose I could handle this in `didSelectDate`, but I'm hoping that there is a easier way to go about this. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if what you want is for only certain days to be selectable, then using `didSelectDate` is at first kind of pointless, because that day was already selected.

What you actually need, according to your description of the problem, is for only certain "day squares" respond to touch input , AND, somehow convey to the user that a certain "day square" is disabled or unselectable, by giving the square a disabled look.

The problem is that Tapku Calendar doesn't allow you to do that, unless you go about and adapt the source code to your liking.

So, going back to `didSelectDate`, as it seems it's your only choice of handling user selection/interaction right now... the user is going to be able to select dates that you ideally didn't want to be selectable, so you should manage that appropriately to your situation.